# How do I find the lower bound of $a_n:=n+\frac{100}{n}$ without inserting values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

> How do I find the lower bound of $a_n:=n+\frac{100}{n}$ without inserting values?

I already found out, that the sequence has no upper bound, because $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n\to\infty$. However, I'm not sure how to go on with the lower bound.

Comment: Look at the variations of $f(x)=x+\frac {100} x$. Can you compute the derivative and look for the minimum of that function?

Comment: Yeah, it should be $1-\frac{100}{x^2}$ and the minimum is for $n=10$ because the fraction will be as small as possible and so the subtraction. This should be the root of the function, right?

Comment: I mean intercept, sry

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means):
$$
\frac 12 a_n = \frac 12 \left(n + \frac{100}{n} \right) \ge \sqrt{n \cdot \frac{100}{n}} = 10 \, .
$$
Equality holds if (and only if) $n = \frac{100}{n}$, that is for $n=10$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This is essentially asking how small the sum of two (positive) numbers can be, given that they multiply to $100$. What does intuition tell you about when the sum of two numbers is minimized when something like their product should be fixed? Can you answer the question when the product is $1$ instead of $100$ and then extrapolate?

On the other hand, if you're familiar with inequalities, something like AM-GM could help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to express in the sentence "What does intuition tell you...", English is not my native language, sry.

Comment: @Doesbaddel No problem. I guess what I'm trying to say is that you should have some idea of how the sum of two numbers should change as their product remains the same, say as one gets small (and the other gets very large). Maybe drawing a graph could help.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I noticed that both function cross at exactly $n=10$

Answer (score 0):

$a_n= n+100/n=$

$ (\sqrt{n})^2 + (\sqrt{100/n})^2 =$

$(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{100/n})^2 + 2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{100/n} $

$\ge 2\sqrt{n(100/n)} = 20;$

Equality for $(n)^{1/2}=(100/n)^{1/2}$, i.e

$n=100/n$.